# Design suggestion for status on card view

Tags: design, tags, status

Alternate design suggestion for showing different statuses on a card view.[image]

Answer (score 4):

Users generally notice the footer section when they have to take some action on the card, else the section might go unnoticed.

## The F of eye tracking

Keep in mind the F of eye tracking on how users scan information on web.

[image]

---

## [Google plus](https://plus.google.com/)

has considered the same thing and has placed the category names on top along with the headlines. **It's much faster to scan**:

[image]

Comment: Totally agree with the concept but in the current scenario of the example i shared has less space to keep it in the same line the title and the status. Maybe a dot may work with a filled color. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Consider *wrapping the tag to second line* when it doesn't fit on the same line. The dot may not stand out, and may become cognitive overload.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can try something like this and include some other data which you have kept in more section.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but i am afraid for the scenario where the user might see many cards in the screen, that might not be a problem for the eye?

Comment: proper sizing and pleasant colors will do the magic without creating a problem, you can also give small illustration like icon also . This was just depiction of the idea.

Comment: I agree with uttham's input but, my suggestion is its better to keep the status badges on right side instead of left.